# how to calculate recall when you don't know about relevant results

Tags: gensim, precision-recall, pre-trained-model

I wanna calculate recall for query"terminator_2" or any movie on google pre-trained model (GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin).but i don't know about the relevant movie.is  there any solution for this problem or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "recall for google pre-trained model"? Which Google pre-trained model? Recall on what task? (The measure of recall requires some idea of the "correct"/"desirable" responses for a query/classification, compared to those that come back via a certain method. What responses are "correct" for your need?)

Comment: thank you gojomo for your response as always.I wanna calculate recall  for query"terminator_2" on GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.since i don't know how many "desireble " movie exists In association with "terminator_2" how could i calculate recall?I wanna use it in my article.what should i do in situation like this?

Comment: i wanna find movies that  are similar to "terminator_2" for example.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question to contain a specific example. Is the token '`terminator_2'` in the `GoogleNews` word-vectors? (I'm not sure that it is.) If it is, you can get a list of the most-similar word-vectors, after loading the vectors into the variable `wv`, by using `wv.most_similar('terminator_2')` – but that will not be limited to just movies, as that dataset has no idea what the type of each token is. It still may be interesting to you. Have you tried that? What were the results, and how were they good or bad for your needs? Do you mean 'accuracy' in its formal definition in IR?

Comment: let me explain my question more. i have made my model based on IMDB user reviews in horror genre filmes.i query "eden lake"  movie and it returns for example n results that some of them are movies that are horror.now i want calculate "accuracy" in IR as you mentioned.the results are horror movies that  are similar to "eden lake" movie.

Comment: this is my top 10 results:1-"wolf creek"  2-"High Tension"   3-"Martyrs"   4-"Funny Games"   5-"hostel"   6-"Vacancy"   7-"The Descent"   8-"Straw dogs"   9-"irrevisible"   10-"deliverance"  all of them are movie. in fact i'm making a movie recommnder system. and i have to evaluate my model accuracy.

Comment: How do you define "model accuracy"? How did you get those top-10 results from teh `GoogleNews` word-vectors? (I don't think `High_Tension` or `Funn_Games` are words in that collection, are they? If not, how are they in your results?)

Comment: forget googleNews.i have trained my model. these are  the results of my model. i trained my model based on imdb users reviews.i wanna calculate recall and precision and f1.if i'm wrong please show me the right way.

Comment: What is a correct response for "Eden Lake"? (Do you have a set of "true values" for your task to use as test data?)

Comment: the only thing that i know is  "more like this"  in this page  "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1020530/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1". i s it acceptable or not?my question is that how to prepare set of "true values".

Comment: Are you intending to crawl the IMDB 'More Like This' results for a bunch of movies, to treat those as the "most related", then score your code as to how well it matches that?

Comment: I don't know. you think it's acceptable or not?is it acceptable for an article?what did you do if you were me? give me a solution please.

Comment: In order to calculate "accuracy" (or "recall" or "precision", etc), you need some idea of the preferred/correct answers. If you don't already have that, then yes, bootstrapping from some other public source that you think does a good job (like IMDB's suggestions) is a reasonable approach. (But also then: if your end goal is just to get such similar-movies, maybe you can just use IMDB's recommendations, and don't need to build your own system at all?)

Comment: if i google "similar movie to eden lake" it returns similar movies also. can i  use INTERSECTION between google's suggestions AND  IMDB's suggestions?then the answer of intersection would be preferred answers. what you think ?is a  reasonable approach?

Comment: It's reasonable to try. Only you can evaluate if the end results fit your needs.